# How to implement in terraform azure for redis with private endpoint?

Tags: azure, redis, terraform

I need help with terraform. I need deploy azure for redis cache using private endpoint. My code:

```
 resource "azurerm_redis_cache" "redis_cache_example" {
  name                          = "redis-cache-ex"
  location                      = var.location
  resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
  capacity                      = var.redis_plan_capacity
  family                        = var.redis_plan_family
  sku_name                      = var.redis_plan_sku_name
  enable_non_ssl_port           = false
  minimum_tls_version           = "1.2"
  public_network_access_enabled = false
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "private_dns_zone_example" {
  name                = "example.redis-ex.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "virtual_network_link_example" {
  name                  = "exampleVnet.com"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.private_dns_zone_example.name
  virtual_network_id    = var.vnet_id
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "redis_pe_example" {
  name                = "redis-private-endpoint-ex"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = var.subnet_id

   private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "privatednsrediszonegroup"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.private_dns_zone_example.id]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "peconnection-example"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_redis_cache.redis_cache_example.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["redisCache"]
  }
}
```

After deploying my redis doesn't ping within vnet. What's wrong with my terraform?

Comment: The problem was solved by adding one more resource azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link: `resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "vn_link_example" {
  name                  = "vn_link_redis_example"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.virtual_network_link_example
  virtual_network_id    = var.vnet_id
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name

  tags = var.tags
}`

Answer (score 3):

You can also add an `azurerm_private_endpoint` resource and link it to `azurerm_redis_cache` (or i guess other resource as well).

```
resource "azurerm_redis_cache" "default" {
...
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "default" {
  count               = 1
  name                = format("%s-redis%d", var.env, count.index + 1)
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.default.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.default.location
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.default.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = format("%s-redis%d-pe", var.env, count.index + 1)
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_redis_cache.default[count.index].id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["redisCache"]
  }
}
```

You can find list of other private resources on [AZ docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#private-link-resource).