# Where to see the effect of Terraform Azure Redis cache setting public_network_access_enabled in Azure portal?

Tags: azure, redis, terraform

I have been learning how to use Terraform to provision resources in Azure including a Redis cache.

I have created two instances with the following:

```
resource "azurerm_redis_cache" "my-public-cache" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.parent_resource_group.name
  capacity            = 0
  family              = "C"
  sku_name            = "Basic"
  enable_non_ssl_port = false
  minimum_tls_version = "1.2"
  public_network_access_enabled = true
  redis_version = 6
}

resource "azurerm_redis_cache" "my-private-cache" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.parent_resource_group.name
  capacity            = 0
  family              = "C"
  sku_name            = "Basic"
  enable_non_ssl_port = false
  minimum_tls_version = "1.2"
  public_network_access_enabled = false
  redis_version = 6
}
```

The only difference, other than the names, is the `public_network_access_enabled` setting. So one is "public", the other is not.

This appears to work, as I can connect to the public one from my workstation but not the other.

My question is where and what difference does this actually make to the two instances and where can I see that difference in the Azure portal?
I've been looking at them both in the portal and I can't see anything different. When colleagues ask what difference does that setting actually make, I'd like to be able to point to something in the portal. But at the moment, I can't.

EDIT:
For clarity, the question is *not* "how can I connect to a private instance?".
Another way to phrase the question could be: How can someone look at the two instances and tell which one is public and which one is private (assuming the names don't give it away and the presence of private end-points doesn't give any clues)?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> Where and what difference does this actually make to the two instances and where can I see that difference in the Azure portal?

- When you set  **`public_network_access_enabled = true`** it will deploy the Azure Cache for the Redis network as  "public" as you mentioned.
- When you set **`public_network_access_enabled = false`** it will deploy the Azure Cache for the Redis network as "private".

When you create a private network enabled in the azure cache you need to add the private endpoints into your terraform code.

**`test.tf`**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}                           
  
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "<your resource name>"
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "vnet326"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "subnet1"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_redis_cache" "example" {
  name                = "privatecache"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  capacity            = 2
  family              = "C"
  sku_name            = "Standard"
  enable_non_ssl_port = false
  minimum_tls_version = "1.2"
  public_network_access_enabled = false
  redis_version = 6
}
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  count               = 1
  name                =  "endpoint1"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "service1"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_redis_cache.example.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["redisCache"]
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

The above code was executed successfully and you can see the difference in the portal.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[How to implement in terraform azure for redis with private endpoint? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73544491/how-to-implement-in-terraform-azure-for-redis-with-private-endpoint) by Tom lime.

Comment: That second screenshot is a difference that you've added though.
If there were no private end point, how could I look at a Redis instance in the portal and tell if it's public or private?

Comment: Refer to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-private-link it tells that when you set the public network access disabled it needs private endpoints.